# How to stop marquee text for awhile and then continue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee

I want when each `<li>` end the marquee stop for a few second, and then continue to the next `<li>`.  this is my code:

```html
<div id="teks_container" >
    <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="3"  height="200px">
 <ul>
    <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
     </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
    </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
    </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
    </p></li><br/>
       </ul>
    </marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: [tag:marquee] + [tag:html5] ? something wrong in here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.start()` and `this.stop()` to pause and start the `marquee`.

```js
var start = true;
setInterval(passStartMarquee, 1500 );
// adjust the delay

function passStartMarquee() {
    if (start) {
      document.querySelector('marquee').start();
      start = false;
     } else {
       document.querySelector('marquee').stop();
       start = true;
     }     
}
```

```html
<div id="teks_container" >
    <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="3"  height="200px">
 <ul>
    <li ><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
     </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
    </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
    </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks
    </p></li><br/>
       </ul>
    </marquee>
</div>
```

I would prefer going with jquery marquee slider instead. As it will be cross browser compatible.

Comment: actually, this for touchscreen device, and it just like digital poster, so i need it stop and start automatically with timer maybe.

Comment: why you cant look for jquery slider instead of marquee?

Comment: @AzeezKallayi yeah you're right, i've tried it, but i'm looking for the simple one, and if marquee could be like that, it will be a simpler :)

Comment: @mohamedrias still the same, that'll be stop when i mouseover it

Comment: Please remove those events from marquee.  Onmouseover and onmouseout

Comment: Updated it. Please check now

Comment: sorry what's the different? i mean, the result still same just like in mine. it continue marqueeing. Could you make the first sentence stop for 3 second when it on the top of the page? and the second sentece stop too whe it on the top of the page? each of the first sentence could stop when their on the top of the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74315/discussion-between-putra-arifin-and-mohamedrias).

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use a none standard html tag because its implementation will differ and may not be implemented in other browsers
read this from mozilla developer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

For better alternative use jquery marquee plugins google it and you will find many just select the one you see it the best for you and use and stop using the marquee tag

Answer (score 0):

If desktop is your only supported platform then you can confidently go ahead and use marque. Marque has two js handlers `stop` and `start` Which you can use to control it.

Comment: could we make it stop when the first line in top of the div for a few seconds?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, just add the following CSS, so each `li` will be shown separately and with a little delay between them due to the restricted `marquee`'s height:

```css
p {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="teks_container" >
    <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="3"  height="200px">
 <ul>
    <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks [1]
     </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks [2]
    </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks [3]
    </p></li><br/>
           <li><strong><p align="justify">
         I was wondering if it's possible</strong> to create HTML Rolling Credits in a website. If so, how do I need to do? Thanks [4]
    </p></li><br/>
       </ul>
    </marquee>
</div>
```